# Overload ostream << operator

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it is possible to overload the `<< operator` in the need for printing an object in the class in two certain way.

For example, I'm building a domino game so I need to print my cubes with the numbers : `[1][6][6][3]`
And print the computers cubes : `[ ][ ]`

Comment: IIRC, it *is* overloadable... so what you want to do is probably possible =)

Comment: The standard uses [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to print the same data in a variety of ways.

Comment: Haha I'm trying to think of a way because I don't know what to change in the parameters of the function as they both pretty much the same only the execute is different :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example of overloaded extraction and insertion operators:

```
/*
    Operator: <<
    This insertion operator outputs the data members of 
    class object instantiation in the format:(x,y)
    The returning type ostream&, allows 
    you to chain more then one objects to be printed.
*/
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, class_name& object_name) {
   return os << '(' << object_name.get_data_memberx() 
             << ',' << object_name.get_data_membery()
             << ')';
}

/*
    Operator: >>
    This extraction operator creates an input stream it
    inserts to it values for of all the data members of
    the class passed by reference and returns it.
    Input format: (x,y)
*/
istream& operator>> (istream& is, class_name& object_name) {
     char par1, comma, par2;
     double x, y;

     is >> par1 >> x >> comma >> y >> par2;
     // check if any input
     if(!is) return is;
     // check for valid input format
     if (par1 != '(' || comma != ',' || par2 != ')') {
         // set failbit to indicate invalid input format
         is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
         return is;
     }
     // assign input values to second argument
     object_name = class_name(x,y);
     return is;
}
```

You could use the above example and modify the formats to match the desired result.

Comment: That would be an *insertion operator*.  Also, I don't think this answers how to print the object in two ways.

Comment: This operator "inserts" the object into the ostream. The extraction operator is the one typically used with `cin`

Answer (score 2):

While the others have answered how to overload `operator<<`, it's not clear how to have two different formats.  I recommend this: temporary objects.

```
struct showdomino {
    domino& d; 
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, showdomino dom) 
{return out << '[' << dom->d.number << ']';}

struct hidedomino {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, hidedomino dom) 
{return out << "[ ]";}
```

Then usage is vaguely like this:

```
if (show_it)
    std::cout << showdomino{d} << '\n';
else
    std::cout << hidedomino{} << '\n';
```

Comment: That's... got to be the most straightforward line out of all my code.  It's just an if-statement as a placeholder for whatever _your_ code does.

Comment: This is similar to how some of the STL's *stream manipulators* are implemented. Most of them are implemented as plain functions and passed as-is to the stream operators that accept function pointers as input.  But in the case of manipulators that have their own input parameters (like `std::setw()`), they return temp objects that remember the input values and have overloaded stream operators to know which streams to manipulate. Not unlike the example above, though using a `struct` initialization is much simpler than how the STL does it.  Same concept, though.

Answer (score 0):

The << operator used for cout is actually the bitwise left shift operator that is overloaded to obtain this behaviour.

I don't really understand what you want to achieve exactly (a code snippet would have been helpful). But, it seems you want to overload << for an ostream and a YourClass type. You can have something like:

```
void operator<<(ostream str, YourClass cls) {
    // generate required output
}
```

Note that this acts as a regular function, just the calling syntax is different.

Comment: It should return `ostream&` not void

Comment: But what if I want to add in addition to that another overload that prints in a different way ? for example : X= Y=

Comment: Then you return an ostream& reference to that ostream, as @Alejandro Diaz suggested. Note that my code snippet is more of a guidance than what you actually need