# c++ overloading << operator error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
private:
int size;
int*head;
```

Hi,I am designing a vector class (for mathematics).My aim is to print the vectors as [x1,x2,x3..xn]. I have designed the constructor as :

```
Vector::Vector(int x) :size(x){
  size=x;
  head=new int[x];
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  head[i]=0;                    // all the elements initially 0
  }
}
```

to access the private data members:

```
     int*Vector::showthehead(){
     return head;
     }

     int Vector::showthesize(){
     return size;
     }
```

and I want to print them as below but I have an error saying:" '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

```
     ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,Vector &v){   
       // free function put in the cpp file but not in header.  
       int*x=new int[];
       x=v.showthehead();
       for(int i=0;i<v.showthesize;i++){
       os<<" "<<x[i]<<" ";
       }
       return os;
     }
```

Comment: In the `for` loop, you want `v.showthesize()`. You missed the parentheses. You also don't want that `int *x = new int[];`. You just want `int *x = v.showthehead();`.

Comment: thanks for the comments but the problem is, in the main when i create a vector and try to print it,it does not work

Comment: If I do const vector & v then I can not use a member function on v

Comment: So your problem has to do with what is happening the main, but you don't show the main function - do you see the problem with your question? Aside from that your are leaking memory: `int*x=new int[];` is wrong (are you a java programmer?). Write `int*x=v.showthehead();` instead. Also please improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: `int*x=new int[];`  This is not standard C++.  Even if you change it to be standard C++ calling of `new[]`, you're leaking memory.

Comment: I understood the problem.In the header file, I have to put the free function outside of the class.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
void print_vector_elements(Vector& v)
{
  for(int i=0; i < i.size(); ++i) cout << v[i] << '\n'; 
}
```

Regarding overloading insertion operator, check: [Overload ostream << operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438553/overload-ostream-operator/29438658#29438658)

Comment: I know how to print elements, you are not answering my question and yes i have looked at that post.

Comment: @Cem Aytekin I was trying to make the point that if you have object with multiple data members (basically a vector type container), a better way to print its elements  will, probably,  be via a function. Print loop inside a operator overload is a rare thing, moreover, first time to see. But, I could be wrong.